# Can't modprobe einj in VM / cloud services

Tags: virtualbox, google-cloud

I tried to `modprobe einj` on VM or Google cloud VM both got the same result as below:

```
[test@instance-1 ~]$ sudo su
[root@instance-1 test]# modprobe einj
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'einj': No such device
```

Any chance any cloud service allow me to do this?

Comment: Verify BIOS supports EINJ first. For that, look for early boot messages similar to this one: `ACPI: EINJ 0x000000007370A000 000150 (v01 INTEL           00000001 INTL 00000001)`

Comment: No, no this line in VM or cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems quite intuitive to me that in a shared virtualized environment, UEFIs under hypervisors should not be allowed to insert hardware faults.

So, this is no coincidence: GCM doesn't *allow* you to do this, so your virtualized machine doesn't get that capability, and the `einj` module refuses to load.

I checked uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_3_final_Jan30.pdf , and I wrongly remembered that the injection instruction language would allow you a ring escalation, but it's not the case (far as I can tell now from skimming table 18-407); but that's not the case. So, technically, the (itself virtualized) UEFI in the VM *could* allow you to do that. But it's unlikely any implementation *will* allow you to do that.

Comment: Why virtualbox show the same error, it is in my computer....

Comment: because it's a hardware function not allowed to your VM. It's simple as that. It breaks VM isolation. It *should* not be allowed. I mean, you wouldn't ask about EINJ if you didn't know what it does – how do you propose something that lets you write to physical registers is compatible with the idea of a hypervisor disallowing a VM doing *exactly* that?

Comment: From a common sense view, this answer is correct. Technically, this answer is wrong. The BIOS and EFI firmware are virtualized. Hardware faults can also be virtualized. I am not aware of an implementation that supports user injection of faults. There is nothing in the virtualization specs that would prevent support for something like EINJ from being designed into the firmware.

Comment: You're right, @JohnHanley. I checked https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_3_final_Jan30.pdf , and wrongly remembered that the injection instruction language would allow you a ring escalation, but it's not the case (far as I can tell now from skimming table 18-407).

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Add those details to your answer so I can vote.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks!